# ReactJS state is not updating in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a `ReactJS` projects with `functions` and when I navigating into another page, set the values of props to the states but afterward when I click a button for logging these variables  logs these as empty.

```
import React, { memo, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { axios } from '../constants/axios';
import { Table, Button } from 'antd'
import { baseUrl } from '../constants';

const Component = memo(function Component(props) {

    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [appToken, setAppToken] = useState("");
    const [eventToken, setEventToken] = useState("");
    const [columns, setColumns] = useState([])
    const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("app token > ", props.location.appToken)
        console.log("event token > ", props.location.eventToken)

        if (props.location.appToken === undefined || props.location.eventToken === undefined) {
            props.history.push("/home")
            return
        }


        console.log("props location appToken > ", props.location.appToken);

        setAppToken(props.location.appToken)
        setEventToken(props.location.eventToken)


        async function asyncNetworkCall() {
            await networkCall();
        }

        asyncNetworkCall();

    }, [])


    const detailOnClick = (event, token) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log("token => ", token);
        console.log("app token > ", appToken);
        console.log("tracker token > ", token);
    }



    const networkCall = async () => {
        var allColumns = [
                {
                    title: 'Tracker Name',
                    dataIndex: 'TrackerName',
                    key: 'TrackerName',
                    render: (obj) => {
                        return <Button onClick={e => detailOnClick(e, obj.token)}>{obj.name}</Button>
                    }
                },
                {
                    title: "Token",
                    dataIndex: "token",
                    key: "token"
                },
            ]
    }


    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flex: 1, width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
            {isLoading && <p>This is Loading</p>}
            {!isLoading && <Table style={{ flex: 1 }} dataSource={dataSource} columns={columns} />}
        </div>
    )
})

export default Component;
```

When `useEffect` has worked `appToken` and `eventToken` is successfully logs (`props.location.variables`) in console but it can not assign to `useState` variables.

What I am missing in the component? What's wrong with this code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using the useEffect here? Why not pass the prop values directly into the useState function calls?

Comment: Where do you call `detailOnClick`?  What `token` value do you pass it?

Comment: there was an `async call` in useEffect, this is why I am used it. `detailOnClick` is an test function. `Button` trigger it and check if its worked. `token` is another `string` value. I call `detailOnClick` from `tableRow`

Comment: @elia: Instead of describing what the code is doing, can you provide a complete example?  Perhaps a runnable CodePen or jsFiddle?

Comment: @David ofCourse. I am setting it.

Comment: Hey guys, I edited it, because of there's a missing network call component but I had to delete it

Comment: You should call useEffect with dependencies and only update appToken and eventToken if required (check them before setting). Otherwise useEffect is being called in every render.

Comment: I guess I messed up. When I add  `[appToken, eventToken]` for `useEffect` dependency, it works.

Comment: @OriolBG is useEffect dependency about view rendering? I think there must not be a necessity for adding value to there. Am I wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't "memo" be used only for pure components?

Comment: useEffect is executed everytime dependencies change (in your example an empty array) hence everytime. The Component being a memo is something I don't know how will behave, but in a normal component it will execute every render loop (a loot, no-good). With [appToken, eventToken] you only modify them once, and if properties doesn't change it won't be executed again. Still I would call setAppToken & setEventToken and only and only if properties need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, I can't see any errors in your code. But you are using a`higher order component` (memo(...)) that memoize your component. Try to implement a `Pure component` (I mean remove memo). Could resolve your problem.

Comment: Ciao, you said that useEffect print correctly (so setAppToken and setEventToken wil lbe triggered). Then you click your button after a while and state is void. It's strange because you setted correctly. Maybe memoize component could cause this behaviour (that I haven't seen before...).

Comment: Very well! So was the memoizarion of a component. I usually use memoization for fuction that works with a lot of data. If you need to increase performance on this component you could intercept code that is the cause of your performance problem and memoize it with an useCallback or useMemo. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Reason your props are not getting updated or getting updated only twice, first initialization with `useState` and then once by `useEffect`, is that`setAppToken` and `setEventToken` have access to outdated value of `props.location.appToken` and `props.location.eventToken` since location is not marked as dependency for `useEffect`. So in the `useEffect` scope, you don't get the updated values for these props.

Also, not linked to yor problem, but you don't want to `async-await` in `useEffect` hook. You simply make that network call and when you get response, your component would re-render as response would result in props update of your component